# Is there a way to check credentials with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase Auth (web API) and am looking for a way to check the validity of a user's email / password combination for account removal.

Ideally a call like `Firebase.isValidCredentials(email, password)`

Problem context: 
In my app, when a user requests to remove his/her account, I want to prompt to re-enter their password as confirmation. If correct, the account should be removed along with all other associated data (living under different Firebase nodes).

While the credentials check is done by `Firebase.removeUser()`, that also removes the auth:ed account with it, which breaks my ability to remove user data (as I've set Firebase Security to require active auth for manipulating user data nodes).

Appreciate guidance here, and if there's a Firebase recipe for removing user accounts along with user data.

Comment: Could a security rule not fix this? If I can only delete the account when authenticated using the valid uid, then I could do that before calling removeUser()? What are the constraints here? This seems a bit too easy.

Comment: Hehe. I think where I'm getting stuck is that I don't want to delete the user's data BEFORE the callback from removeUser(), by which time the password has been validated (but the valid uid is gone). 

If I removed the user data before removeUser() then there's a risk that the password submitted to removeUser() is incorrect and the user would end up in a limbo state (user data gone, but not the account). 

Does this make sense or am I missing something? Thanks, Kato.

Comment: I think this makes sense. Perhaps you should just try calling authWithPassword() with the valid email/password for verification, then delete the user record, then call removeUser()? Does that meet the constraint?

Comment: That works! So essentially, authWithPassword() can be used for already authed users to re-confirm their credentials. Will add that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Firebase.authWithPassword(email, password)` can be used to confirm credentials of already authenticated users, in addition to signing in non-authenticated users.

*(thanks Kato for the advice!)*

Comment: `authWithPassword(email, password)` method does not seem to exist on FIrebase Auth anymore.